# Stackoverflow error when upgrading to JMeter 3.2

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am upgrading to JMeter 3.2 from 3.0 and getting the below stackoverflow error. In addition to this is am not able to validate my script.

```
2017-09-13 16:17:30,804 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: UI Navigation 1-1
2017-09-13 16:17:37,311 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: UI Navigation 1-2
2017-09-13 16:17:38,904 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: UI Navigation 1-1
2017-09-13 16:17:38,904 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$ContextCodeInstaller$1.run(Context.java:209) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$ContextCodeInstaller$1.run(Context.java:204) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$ContextCodeInstaller.initialize(Context.java:204) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase$InstallPhase.transform(CompilationPhase.java:508) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase.apply(CompilationPhase.java:624) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:655) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compile(Context.java:1317) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:1251) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:627) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:535) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:524) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.functions.JavaScript.executeWithNashorn(JavaScript.java:142) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.functions.JavaScript.execute(JavaScript.java:103) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:141) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:116) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:101) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:281) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.SwitchController.getSelection(SwitchController.java:133) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.SwitchController.getSelectionAsInt(SwitchController.java:91) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.SwitchController.next(SwitchController.java:63) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:219) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:173) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.nextIsNull(LoopController.java:151) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:168) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
```

--This goes on for 1000 lines

This affects only one of my scripts, all other run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the stack trace it is complaining about SwitchController this is the clue i needed. I am using a switch controller in my script to run different transaction controllers. I am using the logic mentioned in the [Using Switch Controller: Random Weighted Values](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) page.

```
${__javaScript( var s="0112223333"; new Number(s.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random()*s.length) )) )}
```

It is this code that was causing the problem. It now returns a floating Number object instead of a whole number.

This was solved by my team mate using the below code.

```
${__javaScript( var s="0112223333"; s.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random()*s.length) ))}
```

This code returns a whole number and my switch was working again. This will affect anyone using this logic and upgrading to JMeter 3.2